# Where to set Firebase AddValueEventListener in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an android app with fragments that pulls data from Firebase.

Currently, I have set my `addValueEventListener` inside the `onStart()` method, which is able to pull data from Firebase the first time a fragment is accessed, but when I change to view other fragments in the app and return to the original fragment, the Firebase data disappears until I rotate the screen.

Where should I place my `AddValueEventListener` method to get around this problem?

Comment: Do you want your data to be alive always?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by alive, but I want it to be displayed to the user every time he accesses that particular fragment

Comment: I tried and realised the problem is with a FragmentPagerAdapter that I am currently using within the fragment, but thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** add it to the `onResume` method and remove it in `onPause` method.

**Long answer:**
Fragments are managed by the FragmentManager, which in most cases keeps an instance of the fragment so that it doesn't need to create a new fragment every time you want it to be shown. So the methods `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, `onStart` will be called once on the creation of the fragment or on configuration changing, i.e. screen rotation.

On the other hand, `onResume` method will be called every time you the fragment is taking the focus so adding the `addValueEventListener` will always be called. However, this will lead to add multiple value even listener so it would be a good practice to `removeEventListener` in `onPause` method.

See: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `addValueEventListener` inside the `onCreateView()` method of Fragment. Then store your values into `ArrayList` or any other collection classes. Just show your values from this `ArrayList` into `Fragment`.

**Notice** : You can't store your values `outside the onDataChange()` method of `addValueEventListener`. So just create one method with arraylist param and pass the values from `onDataChange()` method to that newly created method. By this way your data should not be `null` and you won't get `NullPointerException`

See this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) for more information.